# Check multiple div in a form and if div has no specified class do an alert and prevent submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

OK, I have a multiple divs dynamically created in php depending on a variable and I would like to check for each of them if it has a certain class. When I upload an image which will then append the image in the `<div id="img-pick">`, and add a class `allocated`. I would like to check if one or any of the divs does not have the `allocated` class then do an alert and stop the form from being submitted when clicked on the submit button unless all the `<div id="img-pick">` have the class `allocated` to them.

This is my code for the form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="image-form">
<div class="row options-heading"><h3>UPLOAD <?php echo $loopvalue; ?> IMAGES</h3></div>
<div class="row options-content">
  <div class="grid-wrapper <?php echo $model; ?> <?php echo $option_style; ?> ui-sortable clearfix">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $loopvalue; $i++)  : ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $col_setting; ?> grid-item">
        <div id="img-pick" class="<?php echo $option_shape; ?>">
            <a href="#" class="add tooltip" data-tip="Click to Upload"></a>
            <div class="tools">
                <a href="#" class="del tooltip" data-tip="Remove image?"></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="reset tooltip" data-tip="Upload stalled? Click to reset"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row options-nav-btn">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Continue" id="collectImages"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$('#collectImages').click(function()
  if(!$('#img-pick').hasClass("allocated"))
  {
    sweetAlert("Oops...", "You haven't finished picking your images", "error");
    return false;
  }
});
```

With this script, the alert and the prevent of the submit works only when none of the `<div id="img-pick">` has the `allocated` class, but if one or more, but not all of them, has the `allocated` class then the alert doesn't seem to work and the form gets submitted anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
$('#collectImages').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var valid = true;
$('#img-pick').each(function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass("allocated"))
  { 
   valid = false;
  }
});
 if (!valid) {
 sweetAlert("Oops...", "You haven't finished picking your images", "error");
 } else {$(this).closest('form').submit();}
});
```

or:

```
$('#collectImages').click(function()
  if($('#img-pick').length != $("#img-pick.allocated").length)
  {
    sweetAlert("Oops...", "You haven't finished picking your images", "error");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Note: change the id with a class

Comment: Sweet! it works! only when I change the id with the class though. Thanks again for you help!